# why I have an empty list in the output

Tags: python

I have trayed to find the outliers that appear in more than on features but in the output I have an empty list even if there are an outlier in more on feature:

```
outliersIndx = log_data[~((log_data[feature] >= Q1 - step) & (log_data[feature] <= Q3 + step))].index.values.tolist()
outliers=[]    
for i in outliersIndx:
    if outliersIndx.count(i) > 1:
        outliers.append(i)
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Apparently `outliersIndx.count(i) > 1` is never true, or `outliersIndx` is empty. You'll need to debug to find out which it is.

Comment: I print outliersIndx and it was not empty, and outliersIndx.count(i) is always gives one

Comment: If `outliersIndx.count(i)` is always 1 then it is never `>` 1, so the `append` will not occur.

Comment: If it always gives 1 then it will never run. Your condition says greater than 1. Did you mean to use `>=`?

Comment: The condition is right I want the data point that appear in more than one feature.

Comment: @FaDATA But you said "`outliersIndx.count(i)` is always gives one". If it always gives one, then the condition checking if it's greater than one will never be true.